# No coverage information was collected, istanbul coverage. (answer for similar issues in page is not work for me)

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, code-coverage, istanbul

i user this command:

```
 set CODACY_PROJECT_TOKEN=my_token&& istanbul cover --report lcov node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- -r babel-register -r ./test_helper.js \"test/**/*@(.js|.jsx)\"
```

Then i take passed in all test case but "No coverage information was collected" is show.

[image: cmd output]

I have no idea to fix it. can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I used **babel-node** and **babel-istanbul** modules and it works form me.
I am using below command.

```
babel-node node_modules/.bin/babel-istanbul cover _mocha -- --recursive tests/test.*.js --exit
```